# Only allow certain number of seconds for ONE line of python

Tags: python, timer, exception, signals, multiprocess

I want to create a timer so that a particular line of code only has 60 seconds to process.

def foo():

```
 for i in xrange(10):
      output = action(arg1, arg2)
      print i
```

If this action takes more than 60 seconds, then don't print i, but just continue to next one. How can I do this?

action is not a loop, so timer will not work. I also tried signal but that also does not work because I have these nested inside loops and I get an error saying: ValueError: signal only works in main thread // Werkzeug Debugger.

Here's what I have tried with signals so far and the error I get:

fileName.py

```
class TimeoutException(Exception):   
     pass
def timeout_handler(signum, frame):   
     raise TimeoutException
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)

def foo():
     signal.alarm(60)    
     try:
        output = foo2(arg1, arg2)
     except TimeoutException:
        continue 
    else:
        # Reset the alarm
        signal.alarm(0)
```

I do this and instead of raising the exception which should just pass and then eventually continue with my operation, I get this and the script terminates.

line X in timeout_handler

raise TimeoutException

fileName.TimeoutException

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
for i in xrange(10):
    time_start = time.time()
    output = action(arg1, arg2)
    if time.time() - time_start <= 60:
        print i
```

Comment: It doesn't seem from your original problem statement that you need to raise an exception if the function call to action took more than 60 seconds. I just compared how the statement took by taking a tie difference. If it was more than 60 seconds it won't print the loop variable; it just continues doing what it was doing.

Comment: hey Joe, in the code you provided, output = action(arg1, arg2) is something that could as few as 1 second or up to 2 minutes. If it takes more than 60 seconds, I want to terminate that action and move onto next action.

Comment: sorry meant 2 hours*